# How can I add LocationTracking to my WMAppManifest file?

Tags: geolocation, manifest, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8

Based on the code in this presentation: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/MVA-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start-14-Maps-and-Location-in-Windows-Phone-8

...I tried to add the "LocationTracking" to WMAppManifest.xml, but neither the xaml that was shown:

```
<Tasks>
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml">
      <BackgroundExecution>
        <ExecutionType Name="LocationTracking" />
      </BackgroundExecution>
</DefaultTask>
</Tasks>
```

...nor the following, something akin to which the compiler seemed to want:

```
  <ExtendedTask>
    <ExecutionType Name="LocationTracking" />
  </ExtendedTask>
```

...would compile.

Does anybody how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code snippet you have there works just fine. You don't ned to add the entire `<Task>` element as it's already part of the WmAppmanfiest, just add the `<BackgroundExecution/>` nested element.

For an end-to-end example [see this article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Apps_Tracking_GeoLocation_in_the_background) and you can download the sample code [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/images/a/a8/WhatsNewInWP8_FullExample.zip?20121030190717).

Comment: Yes, I added that ancillary stuff inside of the already exist bits. IOW, the three "BackgroundExecution" and "ExecutionType" lines are what I added.